# Exibição de páginas Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, taxonomia

Estou precisando de uma ajuda aqui sobre páginas e exibição com o Wordpress.
Tenho de fazer um site para uma empresa de prestação de serviços, e que essa empresa tem 2 filiais em cidades diferentes, e cada cidade tem seu plano correspondente. Ao entrar no site tem de abrir uma página pedindo para selecionar a cidade, ao selecionar será direcionado para a página correspondente da cidade que irá mostrar os planos dos serviços prestados naquela cidade. E dentro desses planos tem 2 tipos, que são Serviços Residenciais e Serviços Empresariais, como faço para mostrar cada um na sua respectiva página? 
Por exemplo, se eu selecionar a cidade X, mostrar somente os planos dessa mesma cidade e se selecionar o tipo do serviço mostrar somente o respectivo tipo?

Comecei fazendo com Post Type e Taxonomy Type.
Criei uma Taxonomia City e outra Tipo do serviço.
Criei um post type para os respectivos planos, ao cadastrar o plano pode selecionar uma cidade.
Quando entro no site pergunta qual cidade desejo, então ao selecionar a Cidade X direciona para a página respectiva, mas através dessa página (www.site.com/cidade/NewYork) eu selecionar a página de planos, eu perco a referência de qual cidade escolhi e exibe todos os planos cadastrados.
(www.site.com/planos)

Gostaria que fosse (www.site.com/cidade/NewYork/planos ou www.site.com/cidade/Paris/planos)

Obrigado!

Comment: Tem que ser apenas com ferramentas WP? Tem como você fazer javaScript na página, com o editor de texto, serve?

Answer (score 1):

Então man, sua pergunta ficou meio extensa e confusa... Mas se você quer trabalhar com páginas no wordpress, recomendo que você utilize o padrão de templates para diferentes páginas, exemplo:
Quero criar uma página que vai diferenciar muito do meu tema, então o que eu faço?

- Crie uma página dento da pasta do seu tema: "sao_paulo.php"
- Na primeira linha você define que ele será um "novo template":

  ```
   <?php
   /**
   * Template Name: São Paulo
   */
   ?>
  ```

  com isso, o wordpress já sabe que existe um novo padrão de página.
- Depois de criarmos uma page template, vamos chama-la na criação de uma nova página:
  Entre no administrador("/wp-admin") "Páginas > Adicionar Nova", Coloque o nome e na parte "Modelo" Selecione o modelo que você criou(São Paulo).

Pronto, pode programar nessa page(.php), que vai aparecer no WP. Isso é bom quando você quer fazer programação mais complexas trabalhando junto com os códs do WP.
Sei que não respondi totalmente a sua pergunta, mas espero ter ajudado.
See you!